# Destroy Object in unity 2d

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

Im trying to make some point and click mechanics of the game where i will spawn a invisible object and whenever the AI(player using navmesh) the spawn invisible object will be deleted but at the moment the AI and the invisible object meet each other but the spawn object still there and the AI is stuck on the first object

code used

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) 
{
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Spawnmovement") 
    {
        Debug.Log("Collision Detected");
        Destroy(col.gameObject);
    }  

}
```

i put this code on the AI(player using navmesh) to make the AI destroy the invisible object spawned

spawned code

```
namespace LP.SpawnObjectsNewInputTutorial
```

{

```
public class spawnerplayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] GameObject cubePrefab = null;
    private Camera cam = null;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        cam = Camera.main;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        SpawnAtMousePos();
    }

    private void SpawnAtMousePos()
    {
        if (Mouse.current.leftButton.wasPressedThisFrame)
        {
            Ray ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(Mouse.current.position.ReadValue());
            RaycastHit hit;

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                Instantiate(cubePrefab, hit.point, Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Are you sure the name matches? Usually Unity adds the postfix ` (Clone)` to the name when spawned via `Instantiate` in general rather use a tag and `CompareTag`  instead of name `==`